# How to know if a sprite touched the particle emitter

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, particles

i have a particle emitter of fire and i have an object. I want to know when does the object touches the fire. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you mean individual particles? that's not possible

Comment: @LearnCocos2D i mean the all particles, not individually. let's say i am a particles named "fire" and a sprite named "player", i want to know if player touched fire (and of this particles, not matter.) thanks

Comment: and one of his particle*

Comment: then calculateaccumulatedframe may work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

calculateAccumulatedFrame is a method that returns the largest rectangle that includes all of the SKNodes children. This should be able to solve your problem

BUT It might be better creating your own polygon which represents the area where all the particles are usually held and doing a test with that, It gives you more accuracy and gives u more control